# What is the significance of the lines drawn between planets?

Tags: no-mans-sky

What is the significance of the lines drawn between planets?  I've pointed out some of the lines with arrows in the screenshot below.

If I had to guess what they are, they are some sort of orbital path line, but for what?  I've never seen anything following these lines.

[image: Lines]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[These are trade routes.](http://www.carlsguides.com/nomanssky/finding-trading-posts.php) They connect the local space station with on-planet Trading Posts, giving you a reliable means of finding them, so you can sell your cargo (or buy commodities) without having to return all the way to the space station or hope to find one on-planet by chance.

Comment: Wow this will change the way I play the game! It was quite annoying having to blast off into space to do some trading at a space station!

Comment: Interesting.. I thought they were just "space con-trails" that NPC ships were leaving behind, and were just for looks to make the place feel populated.